# For loop duplicating code in Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: html, css, yaml, jekyll, liquid

My input is pretty simple. I'm pulling from a data file to fill `<p>` with content then running the method `markdownify`, but the output duplicates the `<p>` element in (to me) unexpected ways.

Please advise! And thank you.

Sample Input:

```
{% for item in site.data.filename.item %}
<p style="display:{{ item.display }}" id="{{ item.nav }}">{{ item.content | markdownify }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And the Output:

```
<p id="test" style="display:block"></p>
<p>testing output</p>
<p></p>
```

Is there something going on with my liquid syntax? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically what happens when you nest paragraphs. You should remove HTML tags from your content.

```
{{ item.content | strip_HTML}}
```

https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#strip_html

If you want to keep the html formatting, you can use a div to wrap the content, like this:

```
{% for item in site.data.filename.item %}
<div style="display:{{ item.display }}" id="{{ item.nav }}">{{ item.content | markdownify }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks JoostS! This worked. I realize I failed to mention that I used the markdownify method to honor some text formatting that I'm keeping in the data yaml file. Is there a way to keep the formatting, but lose the `<p>` duplicates? I can go in more depth if I am not making sense :)

Comment: You are welcome Daniel. I have updated my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Hey Daniel, can you mark the question as answered? Or are you still having trouble?

Comment: Yes! That worked for me :) thanks and sorry I didn't mark it yet!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing markdownify?
Internally jekyll framework will apply `markdownify` so we do not need to write `markdownify`
I tried your code with  `markdownify` removed and got single lines of `<p>` duplicates.

`strip_HTML` option also works.

Either remove `markdownify` or put `strip_HTML`

Comment: Thank you! This definitely worked in keeping out the duplicative code, now I have the issue that the markdown (why I used markdownify) from the data in the yaml file isn't honored anymore. Do you have any advice on how I can keep the text formatting, but remove the redundant `<p>`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display:{{ item.display }}` try

`display:{{ display }}`

Should do the job! :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question :|